# Support for libprotobuf-c on Amazon RDS

Tags: amazon-rds, postgis

I created a PostgreSQL 10 instance on Amazon RDS with the PostGIS 2.4 extension in my database enabled. I want to test the performance of Amazon RDS as a dynamic vector-tile server.

This hinges on the ability to use the ST_AsMVT and ST_AsMVTGeom commands in the PostGIS enabled database.

These functions require the `libprotobuf-c` libraries to be installed on the system which hosts the PostgreSQL instance.

It seems that Amazon RDS instances have no support for `libprotobuf-c` and PostgreSQL/PostGIS on Amazon RDS cannot make use of the vector-tile functions which have been introduced with PostGIS 2.4.

Does anyone know about means to enable `libprotobuf-c` support on Amazon RDS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just an update to Dennis' comment from the AWS thread, this is now possible.
Quote from the [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=277371):

> We just launched RDS PostgreSQL 10.5 which supports libprotobuf-c.
>   https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/rds-postgresql-supports-minor-versions/

The official release notes (*with **emphasis** added*):

> [...]
>   With this update, we have also added support for extensions pglogical version 2.2.0 and pg_similarity version 1.0 in PostgreSQL 10.5 and 9.6.10; pageinspect version 1.6 extension is supported with PostgreSQL 10.5; *Map Box Vector Tiles in PostGIS with **libprotobuf-c** is supported with PostgreSQL 10.5*; wal2json has been updated to 01c5c1ec in PostgreSQL 10.5 and 9.6.10; and pg_hint_plan has been updated to 1.3.1 and 1.2.3.
>   [...]

<sup>***Reference:*** [Amazon RDS for PostgreSQL Supports New Minor Versions 10.5, 9.6.10, 9.5.14, 9.4.19, and 9.3.24](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/rds-postgresql-supports-minor-versions/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible.

I have raised this issue on the Amazon AWS Developer forum and an  AWS engineer confirmed that the inclusion of the `libprotobuf-c` library is currently being investigated.

[PostgreSQL 10 on RDS is missing libprotobuf-c, required for ST_AsMVT](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=277371) (Amazon AWS Forum)